# html/css div positioning issues with ie

Tags: html, css

Have tried to find solutions for this and can't really come up with anything. Here's the basics of what I want to do.

Would like to have my layout in 3 divs, section 1 is a header (logo), section 2 is a horizontal menu, section 3 is the menu specific content that changes based on your menu selection.
I would like for there to be no browser scroll bar, and for section 1 and 2 to always appear, with section 3 extending to the bottom of the browser window with an scollbar always visible. I'll put my code at the end, but it works fine in FF, but not IE8.  I have read that you can't use top and bottom in the same div, but why not? it works as intended in FF just fine.  I've tried setting top and using height 100%, but since I'm setting the top at 163, it puts the bottom at 163 px below the window.  I want section 3 to grow and shrink as the window expands or shrinks vertically.  Here's my much simplified code. I've used inline styles to minimize working with multiple files and for ease while testing. index.css is inconsequential in this context.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
      http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>Test Junk</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  </head>

  <body>
<div style="background-color:#cccea2; text-align:center;height:136">
    section 1
</div>
<div style="background-color:#ccace2; text-align:center;height:27">
    section 2
</div>
<div style="background-color:#225522;     text-align:center;position:absolute;top:163;bottom:0;width:100%;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;">
section 3    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: I'm having some success using xhtml doctype, working on a good solution.  But I found this on another example while continuing my long search for a solution. I still really don't get why you should not use TOP and BOTTOM on the same div, they are two very different things.

Comment: Using top and bottom at the same time doesn't work, Firefox is using the first one it finds. The only way this will work in every browser would be using JavaScript. If you use jQuery you could set the top at 163px as you are doing, and then setting the height to the document height - 163px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a sample solution using a different doctype.  I still don't understand why people are saying that I should not use TOP and BOTTOM on the same div.  To me that's the same as saying don't use margin-top and margin-bottom on the same div. I don't get it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >

  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
      http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>Test Junk</title>
  </head>
<style>
body {
    background-color:#99cc99;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Times;
    font: Times;
    font-size: 10pt;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
</style>
  <body>
<div style="background-color:#cccea2;width:100%;text-align:center;height:136px;">
    section 1
</div>
<div style="background-color:#ccace2; position:absolute;top:136px;width:100%;text-align:center;height:27px;">
    section 2
</div>
<div style="background-color:#225522; text-align:center;position:absolute;top:163px;bottom:0px;width:100%;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;">
section 3a <br>   
section 3b <br>   
section 3c <br>   
section 3d <br>   
section 3e <br>   
section 3f <br>   
section 3g <br>   
section 3h <br>   
section 3i <br>   
section 3j <br>   
section 3k <br>   
section 3l <br>   
section 3m <br>   
section 3n <br>   
section 3o <br>   
section 3p <br>   
section 3q <br>   
section 3r <br>  
section 3s <br>   
section 3t <br>   
section 3u <br>   
section 3v <br> 
section 3w <br>   
section 3x <br>   
section 3y <br>   
section 3z <br>   
section 3aa <br>   
section 3ab <br>   
section 3ac <br>   
section 3ad <br>  
section 3ae <br>   
section 3af <br>   
section 3ag <br>   
section 3ah <br>   
section 3ai <br>   
section 3aj <br>   
section 3ak <br>   
section 3al <br>   
section 3am <br>   
section 3 <br>   
section 3 <br>   
section 3 <br>   
section 3 <br>   
section 3 <br>   
section 3 <br>   
section 3 <br>   
section 3 <br>   
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sometimes, when something is flagged, we don't always make the right call on this.  I've reviewed the answer, and it is suitable for the question.  If it helped you solve the problem, then you can accept the answer by clicking the check on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Using top and bottom is improper. Just because it works in FF doesn't make it correct. Have you tried:

```
padding-bottom: 1000em;
margin-bottom: -1000em;
```

Comment: Well, I'm not saying that the fact that it works in FF makes it correct, but the use of them should make it correct.  The "top" sets the top of the div, and the "bottom" sets the bottom of the div, why should they NOT be allowed in the same div?  I really don't get why this is improper.

I'll try that padding trick and see how it works.

Comment: Ok, didn't work.  It just made the bottom div really large, which is not what I want.  I want my bottom div to start at 163px, and extend to the bottom of the current window, and automatically expand and shrink if the user resizes the height of the window. I know I can do it with jscript, but i SHOULD be able to do this with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong doctype and are in quirks mode. Use this one instead: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

You say you started using the XHTML doctype which is why it is working better for you cause it's taking you out of quirks. However, you should not be using that one because I'm sure you are not serving XHTML markup.

Also, you have not supplied units in your CSS. You MUST include px or em or percent for any values supplied.

Comment: Tested out the doctype you recommended and it seems to work as I wanted in both FF and MSIE.  I'll check it out a bit more and make sure there are no issues, but thanks for that.
I actually have units in my updated solution, so that was probably a part of my issue.
Sorry it took me a while to respond, hadn't checked this post in a bit.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
          http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <title>Test Junk</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
      </head>

      <body>
    <div style="background-color:#cccea2; text-align:center;height:136">
        section 1
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:#ccace2; text-align:center;height:27">
        section 2
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:#225522;text-align:center;bottom:0;width:100%;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden; height:100%;">
    section 3    
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried that and it looks as if it does basically the same thing that it does when I try to set top to 163 and height to 100%, it shoves the rest of section 3 div out of the visible window. I'll likely have to solve this with javascript, but was hoping I could do it with just css.